# Balancing a dice game - probability question

Tags: probability, game-theory, dice

I am currently developing a TTRPG game system, and I am trying to determine the probability of success in various situations to see how balanced it might be.

The system is fairly simple, you roll a number of 10 sided dice, and if any of them are below your score, you succeed. However, if any of the dice you roll land on $10$ (or $0$ as notated on most d10s), you remove the lowest die rolled, which I guess you could call an imploding dice rule (as opposed to exploding dice, which would allow you to roll extra on a critical success)

For example, my score is $5$, so to succeed I need to roll a $<5$. With one dice, and without the $10$ rule, that is easy to work out as $40$% chance of success, and as I add more dice, I can work it out as by using the chance of failure:

$1-(1-0.4)^n$ where $n$ is the number of dice.

But I am struggling to work out how to introduce the imploding dice to my probability calculations. The chance of rolling a $10$ is $10$% for each die I roll, but when I do, I am essentially reducing the amount of dice I originally rolled, right?

/edit: clarification, if you roll a $10$, you only remove one die, not one for every $10$ rolled

Comment: You asked: "But when I do, I am essentially reducing the amount of dice I originally rolled, right?"

The answer is no, Actually you are defining a function which assigns to each dice roll outcome a real number and you are looking at the expected value of the function over the set of dice rolls, and the probability that the function takes on different vales. As long as there are no 10s rolled the value of the function will be the minimum value, but if 10s are rolled the value of the function will change to reflect the second highest (including ties) and so on. This adds a bit of complexity.

Comment: However the probability of the underlying rolls themselves haven't changed at all. The pre-image of $f(roll) = 5$ will simply include different possible outcomes.

Comment: What happens if two of the dice come up $0$.  Are they both removed, or is only one removed?

Comment: @user2661923 I was originally thinking just one, I'll edit the post to clarify

Comment: Your trailing revision needs re-write, if you intend that you only remove a single $0$ rolled, if there is more than one $0$ rolled.  This is different than saying that you remove the *lowest die rolled*.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, a $0$ on a d10 denotes $10$ not $0$, so the lowest result you can roll is a $1$, and you won't be removing the die that rolled a $0$ as that is the highest possible result (and impossible to win with)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem-statement**: We have $n$ dice and a given $s$ score. We roll all the dice and we get results form $1$ to $9$ or a special result, called WILDCARD. If we have rolled a number of $k$ wildcards, the $k$ lowest dice are eliminated from the table. If any of the $n - k$ is less than $s$, we have WON. Otherwise, we have LOST.

**Probability evaluation**: The probability of having $k$ wildcards out of $n$ dice is $\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n - 1} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{1}{n - k + 1} = \frac{(n - k)!}{n!} = \frac{1}{A_n^k}$. Next, from $n - k$ dice we have the probability to draw greater equal than $s$: $\frac{(10 - s)^{n - k}}{9^{n - k}}$, and the probability to have at least one dice less than $s$ will be $1 - \frac{(10 - s)^{n - k}}{9^{n - k}}$.

**Result**: By summating all probabilities (considering $k$ variating from $0$ to $n$):
$$p = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{A_n^k} \cdot \bigg(1 - \frac{(10 - s)^{n - k}}{9^{n - k}}\bigg)$$

That's all!